# Why not to cast malloc in C whereas do cast in C++?

Tags: c++, c, casting, malloc

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) says that one should cast `malloc` in C++, but should not in C. AFAIK they both are strictly typed. Why is there such difference between C and C++ concerning casting `malloc` or `calloc`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: The link you provide answers the C part of your question in details.

Comment: For the C++ part: don't call malloc 

Comment: "strictly" typed means different things in different contexts (languages). C is not really strictly typed but rather has a set of rules of what is checked and what is not and what yields undefined behavior. While many hardcore C programmer hate me saying this, you can write your C code such, that it compiles as well if compiled with a C++ compiler. If you want to do that, you should add the cast. Else, you can omit it.

Comment: The question linked to (the same as that I linked to) does not explain why there is such difference

Comment: 1. Study the C question, whereupon it's apparent you *shouldn't* cast although if you do it will have a benign effect if you've `#include`d the correct files.  2. The C++ answer is easier, you *must* cast else your code won't compile.

Comment: @Ch3steR this one does, thanks

Comment: Actually, the question should be: "Why not to cast malloc in C whereas not use malloc in C++?" ;-)

Comment: The `*alloc` functions return `void *`.  C allows you to assign `void *` to other pointer types without a cast - C++ does not.  Thus in C++ you need to cast the result of `*alloc` if the target is not a `void *`.  In C the cast is redundant, and is often a source of error (and under C89 could suppress a useful warning if you forgot to include `stdlib.h`).  As a rule you should not use `*alloc` in C++ - either use containers that do memory management for you, or use the `new` and `delete` operators.